# Выполнение скрипта в PHP/JS. Производительность

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте, есть скрипт имитации онлайна на сайте, который просто возвращает число. Не спрашивайте зачем, почему и как.

```
function online() {
    if(empty($_COOKIE['online'])) {
        $d = (intval(date('H')) > 5) ? intval(date('H')) : 5;

        $online = ($d * 10) + rand($d, ($d * 2)); 
        setcookie("online", $online , time()+rand(5, 10), '/');
    } 
    else $online = $_COOKIE['online'];
    return $online;
}
```

Есть такой же  скрипт на JS.

Так вот вопрос заключается в том, производит ли подобный PHP код существенную нагрузку на сервер, если он выполняется при каждой перезагрузке страницы пользователем? Если учитывать то что сайт не статичный, есть новости, выборка данных из бд, и тому подобное.

JS версия была сделана для оптимизации, но PHP возвращает результат сразу, вместе со всей страницей. Вот не знаю что выбрать.

Comment: дак вы выполните эту функцию в цикле N-ное количество рази посмотрите сколько это по времени займет

Comment: место intval($var) используйте конструкцию (int) $var , ее время исполнения в 2 раза меньше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нагрузка на php несущественна, по сравнению с выборками из БД и рендером страниц. Если вам удобнее делать это на стороне php, то можете не беспокоиться.